# (DRF) How to update a foreignkey field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two models, `Account` model & `Thread` model:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Account List"

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    profile_image = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=profile_image_path, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=255, default='Write something about yourself...', blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username", "name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

```
class Thread(models.Model):

    options = (('active', 'Active'), ('deactivated', 'Deactivated'))

    username = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='username')
    alt = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=thread_image_path, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=options, default='active')
```

If I have already created a thread that is `ForeignKey` to the `Account` model, I am not able to change the `username` of the `Account` model, returning the error `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`. I guess the existing `Thread` model require a username to point to. Is there way to create a custom `update` method in `view.py` to update the `ForeignKey` automatically?

Here is my `view.py`:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer 
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

EDIT:
serializer.py

```
class ThreadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    profile_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_profile_image')
    created = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%d %B, %Y %H:%M:%S")
    
    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = (
                  'id',
                  'username',
                  'profile_image',
                  'alt', 
                  'image', 
                  'content', 
                  'created', 
                  'status')
        
    def get_profile_image(self, thread):
        profile_image_url = thread.username.profile_image.url
        return profile_image_url
```

Error:

```
IntegrityError at /account/auth/user/1/
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
Request Method: PUT
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/auth/user/1/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
Exception Location: c:\Users\85291\Desktop\vscode\my-app\web\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 477, in execute
Python Executable:  c:\Users\85291\Desktop\vscode\my-app\web\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\85291\\Desktop\\vscode\\my-app\\web\\jtravel',
 'c:\\Users\\85291\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2022.6.3\\pythonFiles\\lib\\python\\debugpy\\_vendored\\pydevd',
 'C:\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Python310',
 'c:\\Users\\85291\\Desktop\\vscode\\my-app\\web\\env',
 'c:\\Users\\85291\\Desktop\\vscode\\my-app\\web\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 05 Jun 2022 16:40:53 +0800
```

Comment: can you show how are you trying to change `username` of the `Account` model? It shouldn't return any mistakes

Comment: you can use `username = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='username', blank=True, null=True)` so this username filed won't be required, if you need it to be not required

Comment: I am just using the pre-built django API endpoint to change the ```username``` of the ```Account``` model. For those account without ```thread``` attached to it, I can change it without any error.

Comment: can you show the error which you get? because it shouldn't return error for `Accounts` with a `Thread`

Comment: `username = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` delete `to_field='username'` it does nothing, it may occur error here

Comment: I have included the error message

Comment: It worked, after I deleted the ```to_field```. You are right, it did nothing!

Comment: But after I deleted the ```to_field```, the thread model will become ```"username": 1```. I really need to let thread model targeting the ```username``` instead of the primary key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245335/discussion-between-oruchkin-and-david-ho).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete `to_field='username'`

```
username = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

it is a reason of an error